# How can I solve the "name 'bot' is not defined" error?

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, bots

Guys I'm making a discord bot but i have an error it says "name 'bot' is not defined". Can anyone help?
Thanks

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ';')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print("{0.user} logged in as".format(client))
   

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def help(ctx):
   await ctx.send('Help')

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either use `Client` or `Bot` to instance your bot.
In your code you are instancing the bot as `Client`, but you are trying to create a command using `@bot.command()`.

You need to use either `@client.command()` or `@commands.command()`.